# Passing structured data to native code using JS-ctypes

Tags: javascript, c, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I am developing a Firefox extension and I need to perform some high-speed calculations using structured data currently presented in the form of Javascript object. 
To achieve this I'm planning to write the C library to be invoked using js-ctypes.
Is there any way to pass Javascript object to native library using JS-ctypes?
Example of data:

```
{vendors: 
{Oracle: {products: 
{Exadata: {spec1: 111, spec2: 222}, Exalogic:
{spec1: 111, spec2: 222}}}, IBM: {products: {WebSphere: {spec1: 111, spec2:222}}}
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass in types that are valid in C. And since C has no concept of dictionary types or similar you cannot pass those to your C code. So you basically have two options:

1. You use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn this object into a string. You then have to find some C library that can parse JSON and will allow you to work with it somehow.
2. You convert your JavaScript data into types that C can understand directly. For example, you could pass in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes#ArrayType%28%29) of [`Vendor` structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes#StructType%28%29) with each `Vendor` structure containing a pointer to an array of `Product` structures. Of course, your C code will need to know the size of the array - this will have to be a function parameter for the former array and a `Vendor` structure field for the latter.